# What does this IPTable (update, seconds, hitcount) rule do? (debian)

Tags: debian, iptables

```
-- Watch for packets
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

-- Drop flooders
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 3 --hitcount 50 -j DROP
```

I don't completely understand how it works, all I know is that when something hits more than 50 times through UDP in 3 seconds, it will be dropped.

But, for how long? And does it just limit to 50 hits?
And is it 50 hits for everyone or 50 hits per IP?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables:

```
[!] --rcheck
Check if the source address of the packet is currently in the list.
[!] --update
Like --rcheck, except it will update the "last seen" timestamp if it matches.
[!] --remove
Check if the source address of the packet is currently in the list and if so that address will be removed from the list and the rule will return true. If the address is not found, false is returned.
[!] --seconds seconds
This option must be used in conjunction with one of --rcheck or --update. When used, this will narrow the match to only happen when the address is in the list and was seen within the last given number of seconds.
[!] --hitcount hits
This option must be used in conjunction with one of --rcheck or --update. When used, this will narrow the match to only happen when the address is in the list and packets had been received greater than or equal to the given value. This option may be used along with --seconds to create an even narrower match requiring a certain number of hits within a specific time frame.
```

I'd say it's per source IP address, and they will be dropped as long as there have been more than 49 hits in the last 3 seconds from that source IP address.

Comment: So this basically limits each IP to 50 packets per 3 seconds, and if they send more than 50 packets, the IP will be dropped until the 3 seconds pass and they can send another packet. Am I correct with this assumption?

Comment: Basically that's it. Just consider though that depending on the traffic distribution it may stop dropping packets before 3 seconds of "ban". Being a fixed time window it depends on how many packets are received at the end. Just a detail: instead of saying "The IP will be dropped" it's more correct to say that "packets from that source IP address will be dropped".